# Is it possible to iterate through top-level array in underscore template?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, underscore.js-templating

If I feed underscore template with an object like

```
{
    key1: value1,
    key2: [value20, value21, ...]
}
```

then in template I can iterate over it using `_.each(key2, function())`.

But can I iterate through the array if it is top-level like

```
[
    val1,
    val2,
    ...
]
```

May be something like `_.each(this, function())`

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're looking for [_.values](http://underscorejs.org/#values).

```
var data = {
    key1: "value1",
    key2: ["value20","value21"]
};

console.log(_.values(data));
//["value1", ["value20", "value21"]]
```

Then you can do _.each on it to iterate through the list

Comment: And how would you do it inside a template?

Comment: you can pass _.values(data) to template, can you show your template?

Comment: you can just execute statements in <% %> in templates. http://underscorejs.org/#template

Answer (score 0):

Yes. By default, the object passed into the template is named `obj`. [lodash](https://lodash.com/) additionally allows this to be renamed using the `variable` property of the `options` argument passed in; I don't believe underscore supports this.

Demonstrating from the REPL:

```
> require('underscore').template('<%= obj.length %>')([ 'a', 'b', 'c' ]);
'3'
> require('underscore').template('<%= foo.length %>', { variable: 'foo' })([ 'a', 'b', 'c' ]);
ReferenceError: foo is not defined
> require('lodash').template('<%= foo.length %>', { variable: 'foo' })([ 'a', 'b', 'c' ]);
'3'
```

My source is the [lodash docs](https://lodash.com/docs#template); I skimmed through the [underscore docs](http://underscorejs.org/#template) and didn't see a reference to this, so it may be unsupported functionality in underscore.